# Visual Studio Community 2022 v17.0.1: .NET MAUI option is not available

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2022, maui, maui-blazor

When I setup Visual Studio 2022 v17.0.1, these are the options available:

[image: this is how I am getting in my visual studio]

But in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/swwWgFZJvEs), it is showing the following:
[image: but in the youtube it was showing this]

In my copy of Visual Studio 2022 v17.0.1, the option like shown in the YouTube video is not showing up. Is there something wrong with my Visual Studio setup?

Comment: Are you using the VS2022 STABLE edition or the PREVIEW? You need the [Preview](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/)

Answer (score 3):

You have to download the **preview release** of Visual Studio 2022 version **17.1**.

https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/

Visual Studio 2022 Version 17.**1** Preview 1.0 was released on November 8th—the same day that Visual Studio 2022 version 17.**0** was released—and includes not only MAUI, but also a few other features that didn’t make it into the final 17.0 release ([see release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview#1710-pre10--visual-studio-2022-version-171-preview-1)).

Answer (score 1):

Change version to preview instead of other versions

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot it looks like you have the wrong tab selected. Go to the top and select "Workloads" instead of "Individual Components". Then your screen should look more like the one in the YouTube video.

Note that the YouTube video seems to show VS2022 Preview 5 (so 17.0) so there is still some slight difference in what you will see, but you should be able to see the .NET MAUI option to install all the same.

Answer (score 0):

.Net MAUI is not yet available in released version of visual studio, only available in preview version of visual studio. Because MAUI is not yet ready for production. It will be in 2022 soon.

However, if you want to work with .net MAUI, you need to follow these steps:

1. Make sure that you work on the Visual Studio 2022 Preview 17.1 or higher.
2. Download Visual Studio 2022 Preview from this link. https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/
3. Make sure you are selecting Mobile development with .NET under Workloads tab while installing.
4. In the right side you will find an option under Mobile development with .NET named .NET MAUI (Preview) and select it.
5. At this point, click on individual components tab beside Workloads tab and scroll down, you will find Emulators section and select Google Android Emulator

That's all, enjoy your MAUI development.